# Find an item that does not exist in CSV File

Tags: python, csv

I have the below code, it is to find an item, `toFind`, within a csv file.

```
with open("file.csv", "r") as file:
        reader = csv.reader(file)
        for item in reader:
            if toFind == item
```

How can I get the code to print "Cannot be Found" if `toFind` is not in the csv file?

Comment: If any of the answer helped you to solve your question @DW_0505 please upvote it and / or select it as answer.

Answer (score 3):

You almost got it, you just need to check the columns for your element:

```
to_find = "item to find"
found = False  # assume the item does not exist
with open("file.csv", "r") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for item in reader:
        if to_find in item:  # the item exist, declare it exists and stop reading
            found = True
            break
if not found:
    print("The item `{}` does not exist in the CSV".format(to_find))
```

**UPDATE**: As per [Jon Clement](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1252759/jon-clements)'s suggestion, for clear cut cases such as this you might want to use the built-in [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) instead of doing the whole process flow yourself:

```
to_find = "item to find"
with open("file.csv", "r") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    if not any(to_find in item for item in reader):
        print("The item `{}` does not exist in the CSV".format(to_find))
```

That way you don't have to worry about clearly exiting the iteration if a match is found and you can get away without temporary variables.

Comment: Or, just open the reader, and then `found = any(to_find in row for row in reader)`... then you don't need to worry about initialising `found` and additional control flow logic and get short-circuiting thrown in free of charge.

Comment: @JonClements - fair point. I was keeping with the OP style with minimal changes, but KISS always wins. Updated.

Comment: Sure - but one day you'll miss the break out and process a load of data unnecessarily, or you'll forgot to set a default value, or decide to change `found` to a different name and only change it in one place etc... Never hurts to show someone good practice :) (it also doesn't hurt to keep both options in your answer so the OP can pick either and maybe make the transition from one option that works from their level of understanding to the other etc...)

Comment: Fantastic stuff... can't upvote it again though I'm afraid... :p

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
with open("file.csv", "r") as file:
    reader = file.read()
    if toFind not in reader:
        print("Cannot be Found")
```

Comment: @Pitto Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I would implement it this way:

```
is_found = False
with open("file.csv", "r") as file:
        reader = csv.reader(file)
        for item in reader:
            if toFind == item
                is_found = True
                break # No need to keep on searching so we stop here

if not is_found:
    print "Cannot be Found"
```

Using a boolean that is pre-set to False I would be sure that printing the boolean value at the end of the loop it will contain True only if toFind was found in the CSV.